# What is the tool to deploy dockerized apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-ec2, deployment, docker-compose

As a rails developer I use Capistrano and Mina to deploy my apps. Is there something like those tools, but for deploying dockerized apps with ability to rollback in case of any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) may be what you're looking for, various people offer managed instances of Kubernetes to get you up and running quickly, for instance [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/).

Kubernetes can do what it calls [Rolling Updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/) that can easily be rolled back if they fail.